# what is going on with this one side?

Tags: sculpting

So I'm still having trouble with this hair, but now I've run into another problem. 
I didn't have any particular texture for the shapes on Blender and after watching a tutorial instead of just winging it and googling things, I turned it to red and turned on AO. 
I originally had three pieces. The middle, and then the side in which I copied and mirrored. Then I joined them all, and it looked kind of clunky but I didn't see this weirdness until I put on the red texture thing.

Also please ignore the ear I know it's off, I'm trying to fix it but it's not on my priority list rn

[image: pic]

[image]

when i take the matcap off

[image]

Comment: Can your try using the `recalculate normals` tool and see if that fixes it?

Comment: I had no idea what that meant so I looked into how to fix this and it says to select the one that has the blue arrows pointing the wrong way. But it's all one object, and on  the side that's messed up they're pointing inwards. On the other side, outwards. So how do I select the messed up part when it's all one object?

Comment: Go to edit mode, select all and hit shift+n.

Comment: Try to keep the titles of your future questions informative. This one does not communicate anything unless you see the pictures and people browsing the questions see only the titles first. The title should be a clear question shortly describing the problem so it's clear what this is about, something like "How to fix incorrect shading on one side of a model?" would be a lot better.